# Highlighting min/max value table jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I have a table with some compare and highlight data.
And have good working jQuery script for the table. Here is the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/bo7145907/ypob2vrx/8/

I need to change my script for the next requirements:

1. If I have null in `<td>`, text "km/h" should not be displayed. Now I have this code
   `<td style="width: 15%">@Model.ElementAt(2).MaxSpeedAt0 km/h</td>`
2. If I have equal value in some `<td>` need to highlight all of them. For example in the first row "1952" in second column highlighted green, but "1952" in fourth column not highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- for number 1

```
if(!/\d/.test($(cell).text()) && j>0) $(cell).text('')
```

- for number 2

```
if ($(cell).text().replace(/\D/g,'') == min) $(this).addClass("min")
if ($(cell).text().replace(/\D/g,'') == max) $(this).addClass("max")
```

Here's the live demo:

```js
$(function () {
    function getNum(s) {
        var n = false;
        if (s.length) {
            n = parseInt(s, 10);
        }
        return n;
    }

    function getRowData(t) {
        var r = [],
            n;
        $("td", t).each(function (i, el) {
            n = getNum($(el).text());
            if (i > 0 && n) {
                r.push(n);
            }
        });
        return r;
    }

    $("#PlaneTable tbody tr").each(function (ind, row) {
        const values = getRowData($(row)),
              min = Math.min(...values),
              max = Math.max(...values)
              
        if ($("td", row).eq(0).text() == "Turn time") {
            $(row).addClass("low");
        } else
            if ($("td", row).eq(0).text() == "Take-off weight") {
                $(row).addClass("low");
            }
            else {
                $(row).addClass("high");
            }
        $("td", row).each(function (j, cell) {
            if(!/\d/.test($(cell).text()) && j>0) $(cell).text('')
            if ($(cell).text().replace(/\D/g,'') == min) $(this).addClass("min")
            if ($(cell).text().replace(/\D/g,'') == max) $(this).addClass("max")
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.high .min{background-color:pink;color:white;}.high .max{background-color:red;color:white;}.low .min{background-color:lightgreen;color:white;}.low .max{background-color:green;color:white;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><table id="PlaneTable"><tr><td style="width: 20%">First flight</td><td style="width: 15%">1949</td><td style="width: 15%">1952</td><td style="width: 15%">1944</td><td style="width: 15%">1952</td><tr><td style="width: 20%">Max speed</td><td style="width: 15%">989 km/h</td><td style="width: 15%">1104 km/h</td><td style="width: 15%">km/h</td><td style="width: 15%">933 km/h</td></tr><tr><td style="width: 20%">Max speed at 5000 m</td><td style="width: 15%">957 km/h</td><td style="width: 15%">1051 km/h</td><td style="width: 15%">888 km/h</td><td style="width: 15%">910 km/h</td></tr><tr><td style="width: 20%">Climb rate</td><td style="width: 15%">119 m/s</td><td style="width: 15%">131 m/s</td><td style="width: 15%">147 m/s</td><td style="width: 15%">145 m/s</td></tr><tr><td style="width: 20%">Turn time</td><td style="width: 15%">27 s</td><td style="width: 15%">24 s</td><td style="width: 15%">24 s</td><td style="width: 15%">26 s</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: It's working but hides a row with dropdowns and images.
This my site http://bo7145907-001-site1.ftempurl.com

Comment: Trying. Maked <thead> and "Rank" value was hide (2nd row), also the borders of tables became bold. 
Trying paste "if statement" and nothing highlighted

Comment: Try to ignore `<tr>` beyond 3-rd - use `$("#PlaneTable tbody tr:gt(3)"` selector for your `.each()` loop

Comment: Added and now nothing highlighted(

Comment: @BogdanIlkiv : it doesn't make sense, cause [it works perfectly fine](https://jsfiddle.net/dhLn45fc/) when isolated

Comment: Some experiments and all working as expected. In my case `tr:gt(6)` helps. Thank you